# А что(,) если...

Tags: пунктуация

А что(,) если полным семьям педагогов дать возможность внеочередного вступления в жилищно-строительный кооператив?

По правилам запятая вроде как нужна, однако есть случаи непостановки запятой. В каких случаях?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Правильно: А что если…

А. Вопросительное сочетание "А что если" состоит имеет значения предположения в вопросительном предложении, все слова здесь употреблены в значении частиц. Возможна замена  «А если бы…», то есть слово ЧТО играет роль модальной частицы БЫ, придавая сообщению предположительное значение. В этом случае запятая перед ЕСЛИ не ставится.

Б. Похожие варианты из словаря: Что если? (а что если, а если). Что если опоздаем? Что если бы? - обращение с  нерешительной просьбой или выражением нерешительного желания. Что если бы передохнуть?

В. ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ (СМЕЖНАЯ ТЕМА)

В русском языке существуют вопросительно-восклицательные слова, которые образуются соединением слов ЧТО, КАК с местоимениями, частицами  и союзами.  Вопросительно-восклицательные слова произносятся с ударением и выделяются паузой в устной речи, на письме после них ставится запятая. Вопросительно-восклицательные слова следует отличать от сходных с ними вариантов, которые не обособляются.

НАПРИМЕР:

Что ж, я готов. Что же мне, хвалить его за это? Что же теперь будет?

Ну что ж, пошли. Ну что ж, ведь ты при шпаге! Ну что же ты так долго!

А что, разве я не так сделал? А что, ты разве не знал?  А что ты на это скажешь?

Comment: Все так. Добавить нечего.